# The density of M = Median($U_1, U_2, U_3$)

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

$U_1, U_2, U_3$ are identically independent distributed from Unif(0,1). Let M = Median($U_1, U_2, U_3$). What is the density and cdf of M?

Comment: Median is the second order statistic in this sample. [Look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics).

Comment: It doesn't clarify that it is the second-order statistics.

Comment: What is the median? It is the second smallest observation, i.e. the second order statistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the theory of [Order Statistics](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/noteorder.pdf), we can easily find

$$f_{U_{(2)}}(u)=3!u(1-u)=6u(1-u)$$

$u \in (0;1)$

We recognize a known density: $U_{(2)}\sim Beta(2;2)$